# Sencha.ExtJs[4.2]: How to disable only one action button within the handler of the column item?

Tags: javascript, extjs

The code snippet as following:

```
Ext.create("Ext.tree.Panel", {
    renderTo: $(".gsBasciInfo")[0],
    store: "basic_grid_store",
    useArrows: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    columns: {
        items: [{
            text: 'id',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            align: "right",
        }, {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls: 'icon-edit',
                tooltip: '编辑',
                handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {
                    item.disable();
                    //do something
                    item.enable();
                }
           }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Let's say i have the grid panel like above, i'd like to disable this button once clicked, and then something running in background, after the thing is finished, enable this button.

But the only way i found just like my above code, the whole column of buttons were disabled which is not my wish.

My question is, how to accomplish what i want? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`item.disable()` disables the whole column and this seem to be the correct logic (see [this method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-method-disableAction)).

The workaround is to implement your own disabling/enabling logic. I copy-pasted some parts from original `disable/enable` methods (e.g. `view.disabledCls`). You may want to replace them with your own code. But anyway, here's the workaround:

```
handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {
    var me = this;

    if (me.disabledEl === e.target) {
        return;
    }

    me.disabledEl = e.target;
    Ext.fly(e.target).addCls(view.disabledCls);

    //do something

    Ext.fly(e.target).removeCls(view.disabledCls);
    me.disabledEl = null;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/r3Dm3/3/).

And by the way, no need to specify `xtype: 'button'`. ExtJs will use plain clickable `<img>` in any case.

Comment: The issue with the workaround is that once the grid rerendered with `sort` or `expand` , `collapse`, the `disabled` style is gone. You can try to click the column header to re-sort the column, and the `disabled` style will dispear since the grid is rerendered

Comment: @Howard, true. I don't see any good solution for working around the `sort` issue. The only option is to extend `actioncolumn` with your own `enable/disable` methods and proper handling of rendering of disabled buttons on layout refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. This is really a weird feature

Comment: @Howard, no problem. Things would be less complicated if ExtJs would use real components (e.g. as button) in actioncolumn instead of plain `<img>` but this probably would be an overkill.